# Oracle Connection in SSIS error

Tags: oracle, ssis, database-connection, listener

I have searched the message boards and found some suggestions but have not had any luck in resolving issue.

I have an existing SSIS package that connects to an Oracle database instance called 'read_79'. That connection works fine.

I have added a new connection to the existing package called 'read_91' and I am getting errors when trying to debug the package.

> Error =   Error: 0xC0202009 at SMS_Stats, Connection manager
>   "read_91": SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has
>   occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "ORA-12154:
>   TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified". Error:
>   0xC020801C at Import Bulletin Stats, 91 Bulletin Stats [487]: SSIS
>   Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "read_91"
>   failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method
>   call failed.

Here is the connection string that I am using - `Data Source=cm9.FQDN;User ID=read;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=True;`

This string is the same as what is being used for 'read_79' but updated with the 'read_91' data.  And when I perform a test connect from within the connection manager, it comes back as successful.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a tnsnames file or ezconnect?

Comment: I am using ezconnect I believe.

Comment: do you define your oracle server in the connection manager as host:port/sid or as a single name you have on tnsnames.ora file?

Comment: I'm asking since sometimes you may have different oracle_homes with different tnsnames.ora

Comment: Well I am glad that you brought that up.  I did find a second tnsnames.ora file that was in an alternate location. 
I updated that file in the other location and now everything is working.

Comment: been there ;-) Did it work?